# Action not working when button is added with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've added button in html by ajax and it has `onclick` event.

```
if(response.status == "SUCCESS"){
    steps = "";
    for(i = 0 ; i < response.result.length ; i++){
      steps +="<br>
      <div >
        <input type='button' value='ok'   id='button'   onclick='action()' class='button'>
      </div>";
     }
     $('#info').html(steps);
}
```

when i'm clicking on button, action of button not raise.why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#info').html(steps).find('.button').on("click", action);
```

and remove the `onclick` attribute from the button's HTML.

It seems likely that since you are adding these elements after the page load that their `onclick` attributes are not adding event handlers to the elements.

Also, you've got a loop giving each element the same ID but IDs are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code to this -- try not to duplicate `IDs`, they should be unique and avoid inline JS:

```
if(response.status == "SUCCESS") {
    steps = "";
    for(i = 0 ; i < response.result.length ; i++){
        steps +="<br><div ><input type='button' value='ok' class='button'></div>";
    }
    $('#info').html(steps);
}
```

And then use this separately and not within any loop.

```
$(function() {
    $('#info').on('click', 'input.button', action);
});
```